solution in backwards heat equation acting well posed forward in time
I have a question about the equation
$$  \tau\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial\tau^2} = -x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

What boundary/initial value data do I need to make the following solution unique and well posed for $\tau>0$?

$$u_{\tau}(x)= \exp\bigg(\frac{\tau}{\log x}\bigg) $$
It seems quite natural to me to reverse this solution back in time where we reach a singular function in the sense of distributions. Then we can use that distribution as an initial condition.
I've observed that although the equation looks as though it is a backwards heat equation due to the minus sign, for the solution I found, it behaves like a forwards heat equation and becomes instantaneously analytic, existing for all time $\tau$. This is why I'm puzzled.
Here is a diagram depicting (in blue) the singular solution acting as the initial condition, which is a function in the sense of distributions, and we also have a real analytic solution (in orange) as time is advanced:


The heat equation is first order in time and second order in space. Therefore, if you want to make an analogy with it, you should change the interpretation of $x$ and $\tau$ in your equation: the former is time and the latter is a spatial coordinate.

@Gonçalo Okay...but it's actually the same equation no matter what if $x$ is time or space since we're working with a 1D equation. in other words time and space are interchangeable.

@JohnZimmerman This is not true even in one dimension, since in that case we take $t\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ on the other hand $x\in\mathbb R$.
